# How can I have the averageHighTemps function to take the weather database as an argument, and returns the average of the monthly high temperatures

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():

    highTemps = [-3, -2, 3, 11, 19, 23, 26, 25, 20, 13, 6, 0]
    lowTemps = [-11, -10, -5, 1, 8, 13, 16, 15, 11, 5, -1, -7]
    weatherDB = createDB(highTemps, lowTemps)  


    for m in weatherDB: 
        for t in weatherDB[m]: 
            print(m, t, weatherDB[m][t])

    m = input("Enter a Month Name: ")
    if m in weatherDB: 
      print(weatherDB[m])
    else: 
      print("Month not found")

def tempByMonth(weatherDB, month):
    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    weatherDB = {}

    for i in range(len(months)):
      month = months[i]
      weatherDB[month]

    return weatherDB

def averageHighTemps(weatherDB):
#Here is the function
    return


#DO NOT change this function:
def createDB(highTemps, lowTemps):
    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    weatherDB = {}

    for i in range(len(months)):
        month = months[i]
        weatherDB[month]={"high":highTemps[i],"low":lowTemps[i]}

    return weatherDB


main()
```

How can I have the averageHighTemps function to take the weather database as an argument, and returns the average of the monthly high temperatures. This code should only be in the function of averageHighTemps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after but this takes the weatherDB as an argument, creates a list of the high temperature from each month and from that calculates a mean average.

```
def averageHighTemps(weatherDB):
    highs = [month["high"] for month in weatherDB.values()]
    avg = sum(highs) / len(weatherDB)
    return avg
```

You would then probably want to put in your main() function:

```
print(f"The average high temperature was: {averageHighTemps(weatherDB)}")
```